# Link app to dropbox

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have an app with a dropbox link capability. There is a button called link. Then a safari page is opened with dropbox, and you can link the app to your account. But since I want all the users to log in with my account, I didn't want to dysplay my email and passward on the app, but by preesing link, automatically the app is linked with my account, withought showing the passward, amd withought opening the dropbox link in safari. How can I do this?

Comment: For your info update pls just go through the links-> [Dropbox confirms Apple is rejecting apps that use its SDK (updated)](http://www.theverge.com/2012/5/2/2993027/dropbox-confirms-apple-rejecting-apps-use-sdk) and also the official post on dropbox web [Apple rejecting applications which use Dropbox. The horror](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=59350)

Comment: So the only way to remplace it is to create a database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very bad idea. Users should use their own Dropbox account, otherwise you would possibly violate Dropbox's terms of service (you're not allowed to share your credentials) and, perhaps more importantly, any user would be able to delete or corrupt all other users' data.

The only way you could make your own Dropbox account accessible in the app, other than including your email address and password, would be to include an authorized OAuth token which could easily be extracted and abused by anyone who downloads your app.

Comment: Look at this: http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-57432918-233/apple-oks-dropbox-adjustments-accessing-apps-accepted/